# django: adding a form to formset in template causing issues

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I know this kind of question are recurrent here and I have searched around for hours for an answer but nothing this seems to solve the issue.

I have a formset where the user can dynamically add a form. The formset works well when there is only form, but when the user adds a form, this newly added form does not get saved in the database table which lead me to think that there is an issue with the adding button. My limited skills in programming and especially Javascript prevent me from going further in understanding what is going on

here is my view:

```
def New_Sales(request):
    #context = {}
    form = modelformset_factory(historical_recent_data, fields=('Id', 'Date','Quantity', 'NetAmount'))
    
    
    if request.method == 'GET':
        formset = form(queryset= historical_recent_data.objects.none())
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        formset = form(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            
            
            
            
            for check_form in formset:
            
                quantity = check_form.cleaned_data.get('Quantity')
                id = check_form.cleaned_data.get('Id')
                update = replenishment.objects.filter(Id = id).update(StockOnHand = F('StockOnHand') - quantity)
                update2 = Item2.objects.filter(reference = id).update(stock_reel = F('stock_reel') - quantity)
                check_form.save()
            
            
        
            return redirect('/dash2.html') 
    
    #else:
        #form = form(queryset= historical_recent_data.objects.none())
        
    
    
    return render(request, 'new_sale.html', {'formset':formset})
```

and here is the template:

```
  <form method="POST" class="form-validate" id="form_set">
                      {% csrf_token %}
 
                 {{ formset.management_form }}
            
              
               <table  id="form_set" class="form"> 
                {% for form in formset.forms %}
            
                  {{form.non_field_errors}}   
        {{form.errors}}
    
              
             
         <table class='no_error'> 
    
        {% crispy form %}
    

        </table>
  {% endfor %}
        
        
            </table>
         
<div id="form_set" style="display:none">
    <table class='no_error'>
      {% crispy formset.empty_form %}
     </table>
 </div>

         </div>
          <br>
          <br>
          </form>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="add_more">Add</button>        
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" form="form_set">Save</button> 
          
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>

     <footer class="footer">
        <div class="footer__block block no-margin-bottom">
          <div class="container-fluid text-center">
          <div class ="row text-center">
            
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <form id= "form_{{ language.code }}" action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                                <input type="hidden" name="text" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
                                <select name="language" id="">
                                    {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
                                    {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
                                    {% for language in languages %}
                                        <option value="{{ language.code }}" {% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected {% endif %}>
                                        {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
                                        </option>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </select>
                            <button type="submit" value="Go" class="learn_more2">Go</button>
                            </form>
            </div>
         
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <p class="no-margin-bottom  align-items-center" >2020 &copy; Exostock.<a></a></p>
            </div>
             <div class="col-lg-3">
               <a href="mailto: contact@exostock.net"><span>Support</span></a>
            </div>
            
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- JavaScript files-->
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/popper.js/umd/popper.min.js' %}"> </script>
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js' %}"> </script>
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/charts-home.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/front.js' %}"></script>
  </body>

</html>

<script type='text/javascript'>

$('#add_more').click(function() {
    var form_idx = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    $('#form_set').append($('#form_set').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));
    $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) + 1);
});

</script>
```

There is no error outputed, neither on screen or in the logs, but I am sure something is wrong with the form that get created because only the original one gets into db

Comment: I'm sorry but are you trying to show one form multiple time?

Comment: i am trying to show one form from the formset and then add forms (from the same formset) upon the click of an "add" button